# WPF ContextMenu Icon scaling issue on Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-7, scaling

I have an issue with the ContextMenu Icon scaling in my WPF application.
The issue only occours on Windows 7. On Windows 8 and 10 the icons scale as they should.

The Icons are 36 x 36.

Wrong scaling on Windows 7:

[image: Windows7]

And the right scaling on windows 8 and above:

[image: Windows8]

This is how my XAML looks:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="menDeleteItem" Header="Löschen" Click="menDeleteItem_Click">
  <MenuItem.Icon>
    <Image Source="/Eam.Ressources;component/MaterialIcons/action/ic_delete_black_18dp.png"/>
  </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

It also doesnt work if i bind the height and the width to the MenuItem height:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="menDeleteItem" Header="Löschen" Click="menDeleteItem_Click">
  <MenuItem.Icon>
    <Image Source="/Eam.Ressources;component/MaterialIcons/action/ic_delete_black_18dp.png" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=menDeleteItem}" Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=cmContextMain}"/>
  </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: have you tried setting the height to a fix height? 36 for example

Comment: My first idea would be to create binding with relativeSource to Menu item, with converter, and in converter you could get your header as FrameworkElement.Height, I know it's dirty, but that's first idea :P you could also override style to force it's icon size to fit it's place

Answer (score 0):

The solution that helped me:

```
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Height="16" Width="16">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="Resources\copy_icons.png"/>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
```